# Очередь на языке С++

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь решить следующую задачу: создать пользовательскую очередь, в которой каждый элемент равен сумме предыдущих, первый элемент равен 1, второй вводится с клавиатуры.

Вот код, который у меня изначально работал прекрасно:

```
//создать очередь, в которой каждый элемент равен сумме предыдущих

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class elem
{
public:
    int data;
    elem* next;
    elem(int& a) :data(a), next(NULL)
    {};
};

class myQueue
{
private:
    elem* head;
public:

    void push(int& newelem)
    {
        elem* temp = new elem(newelem);
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            elem* t = head;
            while (t->next != NULL)
            {
                t = t->next;
            }
            t->next = temp;
        }
        else head = temp;
    }

    int front()
    {
        return head->data;
    }

    int back()
    {
        elem* tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        return tmp->data;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return head == NULL;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        head = head->next;
    }

    ~myQueue()
    {
        elem* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = head;
        }
    }

    myQueue() :head(NULL)
    {};
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int N, m, l, h = 0, j=1, u;
    myQueue queue1;
    cout << "Введите размер очереди: ";
    cin >> N;

    queue1.push(j);
    cout << "добавьте число в очередь" << endl;
    cin >> m;

    for (int i = 0; i != N - 1; i++)
    {
        l = queue1.back();

        if (h != 1) {
            queue1.push(m);
            ++h;
            l = l + queue1.back();
            queue1.push(l);

        }
        else {

            l = l + queue1.back();
            queue1.push(l);

        }
    }
    cout << "===========================" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i != N; i++)
    {
        cout << queue1.front() << endl;
        queue1.pop();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Однако преподавателю не нравится, что я использовал метод back(). Я попытался переделать без него, используя вторую очередь, но теперь мне выдаёт исключение, с которым я не знаю, что делать. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
//создать очередь, в которой каждый элемент равен сумме предыдущих

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class elem
{
public:
    int data;
    elem* next;
    elem(int& a) :data(a), next(NULL)
    {};
};

class myQueue
{
private:
    elem* head;
public:

    void push(int& newelem)
    {
        elem* temp = new elem(newelem);
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            elem* t = head;
            while (t->next != NULL)
            {
                t = t->next;
            }
            t->next = temp;
        }
        else head = temp;
    }

    int front()
    {
        return head->data;
    }

    int back()
    {
        elem* tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        return tmp->data;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return head == NULL;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        head = head->next;
    }

    ~myQueue()
    {
        elem* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = head;
        }
    }

    myQueue() :head(NULL)
    {};
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int N, m, l, h = 0, j=1, u;
    myQueue queue1, queue2;
    cout << "Введите размер очереди: ";
    cin >> N;

    queue1.push(j);
    queue2.push(j);
    cout << "добавьте число в очередь" << endl;
    cin >> m;

    for (int i = 0; i != N - 1; i++)
    {
        l = queue2.front();

        if (h != 1) {
            queue1.push(m);
            ++h;
            queue2.pop();
            u = queue2.front();
            queue2.push(u);
            l = l + queue2.front();
            queue1.push(l);

        }
        else {
            queue2.pop();
            u = queue2.front();
            queue2.push(u);
            l = l + queue2.front();
            queue1.push(l);

        }
    }
    cout << "===========================" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i != N; i++)
    {
        cout << queue1.front() << endl;
        queue1.pop();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот так нужно оформлять вопросы, но некоторую часть кода можно и не показывать

Comment: А для чего у вас две очереди?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вторая очередь нужна, чтобы хранить в ней числа, которые мы добавляем в первую очередь. Не знаю, как это сделать по-другому, не используя метод back()

Comment: Зачем здесь вообще эти классы? Вам же для построения очереди не надо ничего хранить, достаточно трех переменных `int`

Comment: @VTT По заданию требуется пользовательская очередь, которая создаётся через класс.

Comment: @Антон, ваш преподаватель прав_ в очереди вообше не должно быть метода back(). вы можете вытащить и удалить только первый элемент. Так что удалите этот метод из кода

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Поэтому я попробовал обойтись без него и использовал вторую очередь, но в текущей реализации мне выдаёт исключение. Я пробовал о него избавиться, но не вышло, поэтому нуждаюсь в свежем взгляде. Удаление метода back() также не помогло избавиться от исключения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю зачем все усложняете. Вам нужно делать следующее:

```
int N, m, sum = 1;
myQueue q;
cout << "Введите размер очереди: ";
cin >> N;
q.push(sum);
cout << "добавьте число в очередь" << endl;
cin >> m;   
q.push(m);
sum += m;
while (N > 2) { //два элемента уже есть     
    q.push(sum);
    sum += sum;
    --N;
}
while (!q.empty()) {
    cout << q.front() << ' ';
    q.pop();
}
```

Кроме этого у вас в классе есть следующие ошибки:

```
void pop()
{
    head = head->next;
}
```

А что делать с тем элементом, на который указывал   `head` до вызова метода?  А если очередь вообше пустая?... Наверное переписать на:

```
void pop()
{
    if (!empty()) {
        elem* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Дальше:

- в деструкторе и в методе `front`  отсутствует проверка на пустоту
  очереди.
- в конструкторе  `elem` не нужна ссылька(передайте по значению). Не
  написан конструктор по умолчанию для этого класса(думаю только он и
  нужен там)
- В очереди не бывает метода `back()`, так что его вовсе удалите

  Убрать точку с запятой здесь:  `myQueue() :head(NULL)  {};`